# Connecting Oracle with unixODBC: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, odbc, unixodbc

I am trying to connect from Ubuntu to Oracle in Windows Server. I have installed unixODBC and Oracle driver to Ubuntu. When I try to connect using isql it gives following error:

```
user@user:~$ isql -v oracle-jono username password
[S1000][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

And when I run it with sudo I get different error:

```
[S1000][unixODBC][Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified
```

I have tried many combinations of enviranment variables without success (ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, TNS_ADMIN, TWO_TASK). This is my very first time I am doing anything with Oracle so practically I don't know anything about it. I have also tried to modify odbc.ini and tnsnames.ora files.

My odbc.ini for this Oracle connection:

```
[oracle-jono]
Description = ...
Driver      = OracleDriver
Server      = 111.222.111.222
User        = ...
Password    = ...
Port        = 1521
Database    = mydatabase
```

My tnsnames.ora:

```
Data Source=
    (DESCRIPTION=
        (ADDRESS_LIST=
            (ADDRESS=
                (PROTOCOL=TCP)
                (HOST=111.222.111.222)
                (PORT=1521)
            )
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA=
            (SERVER=DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME=mydatabase)
        )
);User Id=...;Password=...;
```

Is there something clearly wrong? What should I put to environment variables? Do I have to do something in Windows Server where Oracle database exits (for example Oracle listeners)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried many many things and not sure which of them worked but my guess is that ServerName in odbc.ini fixed this error:

```
[oracle-jono]
Description = ...
...same as above...
ServerName  = //111.222.111.222:1521/mydatabase
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I've spent days looking this up and this is legitimately the only correct answer I've found

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for this!

Comment: When I put ServerName into odbc.ini, it checked freetds.conf for the server '//111.222.111.222:1521/mydatabase'. Did I miss anything?